How to rescan connected audio devices after waking MacBook from sleep?
I have a MacBook Pro M2 running on Sonomo 14.4 that I connect my Solid State Logic SSL2+ audio interface to. The interface is connected via USB-C directly to the MacBook where it gets it's power from.
After waking the MacBook from sleeping, the audio interface will power back on and light u although the audio device is not shown as connected. I've always unplugged and replugged in the USB-C for it be recognized again. Is there a way to re-scan audio devices so I don't have to manually unplug and plugin the interface every time I wake the computer?

The post
Restarting sound service?
has this answer by robmathers:

sudo pkill coreaudiod
On older OSes:
You can kill the CoreAudio process by opening Terminal and running:
sudo kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}'`

It will restart automatically after a couple seconds.
That fixes some problems my aging MBP has been having, where it
sometimes fails to detect headphones or decides the speakers aren't
connected. No guarantees it will work for every audio problem, but
it's worth a shot.
Source: zakgreant on macosxhints
forums.

This answer is very highly upvoted, so has a good chance of
working.

I will give it a go, thanks
